# pascal number using while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I need to print the pascal number

```
1
1 1 
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```

etc.

```
import math
i = 0
j = 1
while j<6:
    while i<6:
        print(int(math.factorial(5)/(math.factorial(i)*math.factorial(5-i))), end="  ")
        i += 1
    print(int(math.factorial(j)/(math.factorial(i)*math.factorial(j-i))))
    j += 1
```

it is stated that factorial cannot be negative, although I don't think it is negative.

Comment: In the first iteration of j, j is 1, and then in the third iteration of i, i is 2, so `j-i` *is* negative.

Comment: can u give me solution?

Comment: Yes, make sure that i is not greater than j.

Comment: @ygnaiyu did the solution i proposed word for you? If so, please mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code, this gives the correct output, even though you can work on making it pretty

```py
n = 5

for j in range(1, n + 1):
    row = 1
    for i in range(1, j + 1):
        print(row)
        row = row * (j - i) // i
    print(" ")
```

We know that ith entry in a row of the triange is binomial coefficiant  of (j, i) and that all the rows must start with the number 1, and that's why this works. And ofcourse we do integer division.

The for loops can be replace with while loops as you see fit.